# size of camera preview overlay

Tags: android, camera, overlay

I want to make an app where I have a Canvas on top of a Camera-preview for me to draw on. The canvas should be the same as the camera-preview. But when I get the width and height of the SurfaceView that displays the camera-preview the getters return zero.

I understand why this is (layouting has not yet been done), but I'm not sure how to work around it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The size will be set when you receive [surfaceChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html#surfaceChanged%28android.view.SurfaceHolder,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) callback. But usually you can setup the XML layout such that both preview surface and the overlay view have same dimensions.